# Ionic Project keeps on reloading in chrome

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I have started a new project on ionic framework. When I do inspect element in chrome, the page keeps on reloading itself. 
i found some how a way to trick this but i need to solve it once for all
Any solutions?

Comment: can you post the `.run` and first controller your app lands on.
have you tried with `ionic serve` also?

Comment: i run my app using ionic serve and its new blank project in ionic when it first run everything seems fine but when i click right and choose inspect elements it start reloading i guess the issue here is with the navigator. thanks